# Set ItemSource/DataSource of an AutoCompleteBox in Windows Phone 8 to a database table created in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: c#, mysql, windows-phone-8

Two parts to this question

1. So I've successfully got an AutoCompleteBox working with a local class file called Search.cs I followed [this](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_use_Auto_Complete_Box_in_Windows_Phone) tutorial in order to do so using the IENumerable interface to bind the AutoCompleteBox to the "Search" class file.

Now I'm wondering, is it possible to do the same, except retrieve results from a table found in a Database in PHPMyAdmin on a hosted server? If so, how would I go about doing this?

1. How do you create get the Search Results to "Do Something", say if I wanted the search result to link to an external webpage via a basic hyperlink, or to another page in-app, what would I have to modify or add in? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin is a tool to manage a MySQL database rather than a database itself, so you probably mean you want to connect to a hosted MySQL instance. This is possible, but what you probably want to do is write some server-side software that exposes an API rather that having full database access publicly available.

So then you'll have the server-side application waiting to be called. The Windows Phone application will fire off a request and wait for the response. The server application, when it gets that request, will do all the proper sanitizing of user-input data before running your query on the database and returning the properly-escaped results. How exactly you implement that API is up to your needs. Once the Windows Phone application gets back the response, it can build the page it displays to the user, which, yes, you can include hyperlinks. Make that part of the API response if you store the URL in the database.